# Typing a factory function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a runtime-constructed list of functions which are initialized with an argument, and return different things:

```
 mythings: [
   param => ({foo: param, bar: 2}),
   param => ({baz: param, qux: 4}),
 ]
```

Now I want to write a factory function to create a subset of these things, like:

```
const createThings = (things) => things.map(thing => thing("param"));
```

I'm struggling typing the factory function. My recent attempt looks like this:

```
// MyCreator?

const createThings = <T>(things: MyCreator<T>[]) =>
  things.map(thing => thing("param"));
```

But this attempt does not work. Any idea?

Comment: things is not used in your createThings function and client neither in your last example

Comment: @schneck, maybe you meant to pass creators as argument instead of mythings in your second snippet ?

Comment: @jo_va basically, `mythings` is a list of creators

Comment: @schneck `mythings` in your question are objects with a property `myfunction*` but then you use them `things` as functions. It this a mistake ? Also when you say creators, these are just regular functions or class constructors ? It matters for creating the right types.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir right, that was a mistake, thanks. The creators are just ordinary functions, as in `mythings`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use mapped array/tuples to extract the return type from each item in the array:

```
const mythings = [
   (param: string) => ({foo: param, bar: 2}),
   (param: string) => ({baz: param, qux: 4}),
 ]
type AllReturnTypes<T extends Array<(...a: any[])=> any>> = { 
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...a: any[])=> infer R?R:never
}

const createThings = <T extends Array<(...a: any[])=> any>>(things: T): AllReturnTypes<T> =>
  things.map(thing => thing("param") )as any; // assertion necessary unfortunately 

createThings(mythings) // ({ foo: string; bar: number; } | { baz: string; qux: number; })[]
```

You can also make `myThings` a tuple type so you get more acurate types for each index in the result:

```
function tuple<T extends any[]>(...a: T) {
    return a;
}
const mythings = tuple(
    (param: string) => ({ foo: param, bar: 2 }),
    (param: string) => ({ baz: param, qux: 4 }),
)

let r = createThings(mythings) // [{ foo: string; bar: number; }, { baz: string; qux: number; }
```

Or in typescript 3.4 you can use [`as const`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510):

```
const mythings = [
    (param: string) => ({ foo: param, bar: 2 }),
    (param: string) => ({ baz: param, qux: 4 }),
] as const
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Since I've got to use TS 3.2, your first suggestions are applicable.
I just added both, and both work, there's just on thing left: The creator return type cannot be derived while developing. If 'm passing in a specific creator function, is there any way to infer it?

Comment: @schneck mapped tuples were introduced in 3.1 so all except the last one should work. (ie the `as const` version)